# Entity Framework code first - generate Cascade delete scripts for existing database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework - code first approach to manage my databases. I have a requirement to implement Cascade Delete on few tables. I have implemented it using [Required] attribute. It is working fine for the new databases.

When I try to generate scripts for updating the existing databases (update-database -scripts), no changes have been identified. The migration file generated has got no changes in it.

Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

It would be helpful if anyone guide me with generating the scripts for Cascade delete.

Comment: The migration file generated has no changes in it because they were not code first changes, but database first changes. When you do changes directly in the database they will not be displayed in the migration's file.

Comment: About cascade delete, you have this site: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx that explains how to do it in diferent scenarios.